# How to embed or scrape the section "About This Dataset" given in a Socrata dataset API Docs page?

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-requests, socrata

This page link is for a Socrata **API Docs** page for a public [NYC dataset](https://dev.socrata.com/foundry/data.cityofnewyork.us/qiz3-axqb):

On the top right of the page, there is a colophon/cartouche that lists some information about the dataset:
["About This Dataset"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyIFX.png)

Its last line enables a copy of the code needed to "Embed Theses Docs".
I have tried it. It works but the entire page is embedded.

I would like to embed this colophon every time I access the dataset so that I show this information in my report.

I know where this information is located in the html tree:

```
<body class="dev foundry 200" ...>
  ...
  <div class="container-fluid content">
    ...
    <div id="foundry-docs">
       ...
       <div class="pull-right sidebar metadata">
          <div class="panel panel-info about">
            ...
            < div class="panel-body">
              <ul>
              <li>...</li>  ==> items (9) needed
```

So, I tried to scrape that information using beautifulsoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

data_api_page = 'https://dev.socrata.com/foundry/data.cityofnewyork.us/qiz3-axqb'  


page = requests.get( data_api_page )

print(page.status_code)
print(page.headers['content-type'])

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

all_divs = soup.find(name='div', attrs={'class':'panel panel-info about'})
for tag in all_divs.children:
    print(tag)
```

Nothing is returned (even with find_all): what am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

PS: The other reason, besides annotating a report with this info, is that I want to retrieve the dataset row count *before* accessing the dataset in order to bypass the 1000-records limit of the Socrata API (v2.1 has the same limit as the prior version) and retrieve the entire dataset.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things might be useful and doesn't include scraping. There is a [metadata API end-point](https://socratametadataapi.docs.apiary.io/#introduction/endpoints) where you can retrieve a lot of the descriptions of the data. Here is the metadata endpoint for that NYC data: `http://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/metadata/v1/qiz3-axqb`.

Unfortunately, the metadata API does not include row count. For that, might be simpler to assemble a SoQL query that simply returns the count, such as: `https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/qiz3-axqb.json?$select=count(date)`

Comment: Thanks Tom, but I had check ALL the files related to that dataset. And yes, I ended up getting the row count with an initial call (as per my own answer).

Answer (score 0):

Yes Tom: the metadata API has a ton of info, except the row count...

This is what I am doing to retrieve the entire dataset via the authenticated client:

```
# First call to obtain the dataset size: count of rows:
LIM = client.get(MVD_collisions, select='COUNT(*) as tot')
LIM = int(LIM[0]['tot'])

# Retrieval call:
results = client.get(MVD_collisions, limit=LIM)
```

One day, I'll figure out how to scrape the row count from the summary data at the bottom of DATAPAGE = 'https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Public-Safety/NYPD-Motor-Vehicle-Collisions/h9gi-nx95'...

Answer (score 0):

I have this better solution, which does not involve sending a SQL count over all rows:

```
def get_rows_from_metadata(metadata):
    rows = -1  #something went wrong if output
    for c in metadata['columns']:
        if c['name'] == 'UNIQUE KEY':
            try:
                rows = int(c['cachedContents']['not_null'])
            except:
                rows = 0
            break

    return rows

dataset_rows = get_rows_from_metadata(metadata)
```